# Is it possible to customise the web database template in sharpoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I need to create a custom Web database template(list) like Project database template and asset databse template. where my own user defined columns i want to specify. Is it possible to customize the web database template?

Answer (score 1):

There are [various databases](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678868.aspx) that SharePoint uses. One of this database is the Model Database

> model database
>
> The model database is used as the template for all databases created
>   on the SQL Server instance. Any modifications made to the model
>   database are also applied to all databases created afterward.

For more information about tuning sql for SharePoint there is a nice [Jump start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/tuning-sql-server-2012-for-sharepoint-2013-jump-start) available.